# JavaScript - Get element height value with px

Tags: javascript, html

So my objective is to get the height of an element whith the px.

I already know my height value, but does not bring the xp.

This is what i have done to get my value :

```
  let elemHeight = document.querySelector(".user-name").clientHeight;

  console.log(elemHeight);
```

I need some help figuring out how to get the px.

Thank you !

Comment: Can you please provide bit more code.. HTML of it

Comment: `elemHeight += 'px';`

Comment: Tavish - my html is very simple, i just need to know the height and give it some pixels.

Comment: Ammar, could you explain please !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var css = document.querySelector('.user-name');
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(css).height);
```

Comment: .Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

The `clientHeight` is the px value so using concatenation you can just do the following:

```js
let elemHeight = document.querySelector(".user-name").clientHeight;
let elemHeightPx = elemHeight + 'px';
console.log(elemHeightPx);
```

```html
<div class="user-name">
  Show me the px value in the box below!
</div>
```

Comment: Paul, Like this it will become a string, i need to have the real height whit px, not a string like 56px, the px need to be unit and not string. Thanks for the help